# @Range not working in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I am using spring mvc and trying to validate user input in a form `addGoal.jsp` by using `@Range` in my model `Goal`.But if I enter value for ex `223` greater than `120` as I set in the annotation it prints `Result Errors false`(as I printed in updateGoal method in controller) and not routing to `addGoal` view I cant seem to understand why its not validating the `result.hasErrors()` giving me false even if I enter value that are not in range.

Model

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range;

public class Goal {

    @Range(min = 1,max = 120)    // validation not working
    private int minutes;

    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

}
```

Controller

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import testspring.model.Goal;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("goal")
public class GoalController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/addGoal",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addGoal(Model model){
        Goal g=new Goal();
        g.setMinutes(10);
        model.addAttribute("goal", g);
        return "addGoal";       
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addGoal",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateGoal(@Valid @ModelAttribute ("goal") Goal goal,BindingResult result){

        System.out.println("Result Errors "+result.hasErrors());
        System.out.println("Minutes Updated "+goal.getMinutes());
        if(result.hasErrors())
        return "addGoal";
        return "redirect:addMinutes.html";      
    }

}
```

addGoal.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form commandName="goal">

<table>
<tr>
<td>Enter Minutes</td>
<td><form:input path="minutes"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input type="submit" value="Enter Goal Minutes">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

servlet-config.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="testspring" />

        <mvc:annotation-driven />
        <mvc:resources location="pdfs" mapping="/pdfs/**"/>

        <mvc:interceptors>

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language"></property>
        </bean>
        </mvc:interceptors>

        <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"></property>
        </bean>


        <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" >
      <property name="basename" value="messages"></property>
        </bean>

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>testspring</groupId>
  <artifactId>FitnessTracker</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>FitnessTracker Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>FitnessTracker</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

I have posted my xmls in order anyone wants to see.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You don't seem to have a validator bean defined anywhere.

Comment: Your hibernate-validator is provided remove the scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pom you have the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The culprit is `<scope>provided</scope>`. For Bean Validation to work there has to be an implementation on the class path. This is the case while coding, however it isn't the case when deployed (as the dependency isn't packaged in the war).

Spring will only register a `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` if there is a JSR-303 implementation available else it won't and the validations don't work.

The fix is to simply remove `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Comment: I have the same issue, but I don't have `scope` tag there.

Comment: I had `<scope>test</scope>`. Removing it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem even after removing the scope tag.Then I deleted the hibernate folder from my local repository that is C:\Users\computerName\.m2\repository\org\hibernate and then used maven update to download all jars related to hibernate again.Now it is working fine.